Esim integration with Flutter
Has anyone successfully added eSIM functionality to their app? I'm currently stuck and could really use some guidance.
I'm using the flutter_esim package, and the first step is to request the eSIM entitlement. I submitted the request through the suggested URL here but haven't received a response from the App Store for 3 weeks. Even after reaching out to customer support, I still haven't had any luck.
My questions are:
How can I expedite or ensure the approval of the eSIM entitlement request?
Where can I find or generate the GID1, GID2, MCC, and MNC keys that need to be added to the Info.plist?
For context, I'm integrating with Airalo.
